# PDF Batch Process Edit Bookmark Properties - Acrobat Pro

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, pdftk

I created bookmarks in pdf using pdftk.  But all the bookmarks are set to zoom to fit. I want to edit the properties of all the bookmarks to zoom to width.  I have acrobat pro.  Please help.

Comment: Posssible dupe of [Can I quickly override preset zooms for bookmarks in adobe pdf document?](http://superuser.com/q/256835)

Comment: See also [pdftk force use FIT while update_info to bookmark destination](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/1234494) - bug report

Comment: @DavidPostill,  Thank you.  I am using windows 7.  Pl guide me how to use this patch.  I also came across this in Google search, but not sure how to use it.

Comment: I've no idea. I've never built pdftk.